# Validate if a list has only None elements, strings that only have whitespaces or is empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, validation

```py
#examples:
lista = ["   ", None, None, "", "  "] #print 'yes!'
lista = [] #print 'yes!'
lista = ["   ", None, None, "", " s"] #print  'no!'
lista = ["sun is bright", "aa", "Hello!"] #print  'no!'

if not any(lista) or all(x in ('', None) for x in lista):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Considering that the lists that have only strings with empty spaces or have None values, are lists that, although they have information, this information is not really useful, so I needed to create a validation to identify if a list belongs to this type of list with no useful information

I was having trouble putting together a program that prints "yes" if the list[] is empty, has only strings of empty spaces, or has only None elements, and prints "no" otherwise.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You have a problem with the strings with whitespaces. You'll have to handle them somehow.

Comment: Strings with spaces are not falsy; they will evaluate as true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lista = ["   ", None, None, "", "  "] #print 'yes!'
# lista = [] #print 'yes!'
# lista = ["   ", None, None, "", " s"] #print  'no!'
# lista = ["sun is bright", "aa", "Hello!"] #print  'no!'

if all(not x or not x.strip() for x in lista):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
if all(not x or not x.strip() for x in lista):
```

for the check.

`not x` checks for `None` and the empty string.

`not x.strip()` checks for string with whitespace only.

If `all` gets an empty sequence (or iterator) as argument, it returns `True`, therefore the empty list will print "Yes".